# Debezium cassandra CDC plugin installation in cassandra node

Tags: debezium

I followed the debezium documentation in https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/cassandra.html and downloaded jar files for Cassandra plugin from https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/install.html.
But still, I have not found any documentation on running the jar files in Cassandra node. On running

```sh
java -jar /debezium/plugin/debezium-connector-cassandra/debezium-connector-cassandra-1.1.1.Final.jar /debezium/conf/conf.properties
```

I have the error

```
no main manifest attribute, in /debezium/plugin/debezium-connector-cassandra/debezium-connector-cassandra-1.1.1.Final.jar
```

Comment: Are you trying to run Debezium within Kafka Connect (which is the usual approach), or embedded? ref: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/development/engine.html

Comment: @RobinMoffatt, My approach is different than Debezium within Kafka Connect. According to the documentation (https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/cassandra.html#deploying-a-connector) its inside a Cassandra node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we need to update the installation instructions and/or packaging.

Could you please try to download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/debezium/debezium-connector-cassandra/1.1.1.Final/debezium-connector-cassandra-1.1.1.Final-jar-with-dependencies.jar and then run it via `java -jar` ?

If it works for you please create a Jira issue so we can fix it.